# Dell XPS 13 9365 - can't login using fingerprint-reader

Tags: dell, xps, fingerprint-reader

Recently I have bought a 2nd-hands xps 13 9365 with W10 installed on it. I prefer to use Ubuntu so I downloaded/installed 23.04.

Setting up fingerprint-reader was easy (at least I think so) and both index fingers have been scanned/registered. But when I want to use the fingerprint-reader to come out of suspend mode it failed to do so (fingers are not red and password is required)

As mentioned it was working under W10, so I know it is not the HW. What can I do to have it working correctly?

Thank you for your support.